# deselect mutliselection element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiselect.js

I have function which should clear multiselection element values

```
function multiselectDeselectAll($el) {
   $('option', $el).each(function (element) {
        $el.multiselect('deselect', $(this).val());
   });
}
```

rendered html is

```
<select id="myMultiselect" class="multiselect form-control" name="MyNumbers" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
   <option value="One">One</option>
   <option value="Two">Two</option>
   <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
```

and I'm calling to deselect like

```
multiselectDeselectAll('#myMultiselect');
```

but I'm getting error

> TypeError: $el.multiselect is not a function
>
> $el.multiselect('deselect', $(this).val());

Comment: Because multiselect is not a function. There is no function like multiselect in jquery unless u r using some third party extension or u extended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `removeAttr` to deselect options

Try:

```
$('#myMultiselect option').removeAttr('selected');
```

or

```
$('option[value="One"],option[value="Two"]').removeAttr('selected');
```

for a particular set of options

Answer (score 0):

As this function doesn't exists, you can do a loop to deselect all options.

```
var q=document.getElementById('myMultiselect').children; // get elements into "#myMultiselect"
for(var i=0,len=q.length;i<len;i++){ // a loop for each "#myMultiselect" element
    q[i].removeAttribute("selected"); // remove the attribute called selected
}
```

**Note:** I used JavaScript functions, but you can use jQuery to make it smaller.